# react native android studio emulator not working

Tags: android, reactjs, native, emulation

I reviewed all the documentation properly and did everything as described, but when I try to run the emulator, the project gives this error.

info JS server already running.

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully
  info Launching emulator...
  info Successfully launched emulator.
  info Installing the app...
  Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
  :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
  :ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masa�st�\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masa�st�\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\RNFirstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 10s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\oktay\OneDrive\Masaüstü\RNFirstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: same issue when tried to open the project in Anroid Studio, have you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to downgrade my nodejs version to 10.15.0.

I switched back to the LTS version (19.0), but when I checked the node version used inside Android Studio with *Run Anything* (I managed to find it with this step: **Help tab > Find Action > Type "Run Anything" > Type "node -v"**)

[image: Run Anything]

It turns out my node version is still 10.15.0 so I have to put an alias on it as default with `nvm alias default <version>`, restart Android Studio and my problem solved